# USAID DDL - program codes

Tags: state, usaidopen

The USAID website has a [Development Data Library Submission Form](http://www.usaid.gov/data/DDLsubmissions)

For the *program code* field: is this associated with the award funding the creation of the data set or is this related to the specific data set?

Answer (score 3):

Our apologies for the delay.  We are updating our settings here and will strive to respond within 48 hours to future inquiries.  Per [Project Open Data](https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/), the individual metadata fields correspond to the specific "data asset" (or dataset) which you are describing.

A single USAID award could generate data corresponding to every single program code.  Therefore using the program code to refer to an entire award would be of little value.

Comment: thanks. so the specific program code is up to the discretion of the implementing partner/AOR/COR to determine?

Comment: StackExchange says my response must be 30 characters, when the most appropriate response is simply "yes."