# Making changes to data already posted

Tags: usaidopen

We have posted data for a survey for [Feed the Future](https://www.feedthefuture.gov/) and want to know how to make changes to what has already been posted to DDL?

Answer (score 3):

From [the question here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4819/usaid-ddl-program-codes) it looks as though the DDL has a form for data submission on their website: https://www.usaid.gov/data/DDLsubmissions